# How do I mark an attribute of an object as sensitive?

Tags: azure, terraform

I want to bundle several variables in an object. The object would look something like this (simplified)

```
variable "my_resource" {
  type = object({
    username = string
    password = string
  })
}
```

How do I mark `password` as sensitive? Can I just do `sensitive(string)`?

Comment: I believe the `sensitive` parameter functionality applies to the entire variable declaration block. Individual parameters (similar to your desired goal) in a resource or data source schema can be marked as sensitive, but that is a completely different interface.

Comment: Could you maybe provide an example how to do it @MatthewSchuchard?

Comment: An example of what: indicating `my_resource` as sensitive?

Comment: In short, you cannot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the *declaration* level Terraform only tracks sensitivity for the entire variable at once, like this:

```
variable "my_resource" {
  type = object({
    username = string
    password = string
  })
  sensitive = true
}
```

In situations like yours where that's too conservative, you can override Terraform's built-in treatment of sensitivity in a local value, using [the `nonsensitive` function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/nonsensitive):

```
# (also include the same variable declaration as above)

locals {
  my_resource = {
    username = nonsensitive(var.my_resource.username)
    password = var.my_resource.password
  }
}
```

In the rest of your module you can refer to `local.my_resource` instead of `var.my_resource` to get the version with the more specific sensitivity markings. This approach is intended to "fail closed" by treating everything as sensitive by default and then explicitly unmasking only the specific attributes that you know should never be sensitive.

(It is also possible to orient this the other way around -- having the input variable not marked as sensitive and then the local value making the password sensitive using `sensitive(var.my_resource.password)`, but that approach "fails open" if you accidentally refer to `var.my_resource.password` instead of `local.my_resource.password`, so I think that's a more problematic approach.)